# How to play a video in a AVPlayerView from another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a AVPlayerView in a View Controller. I have another View Controller with one button ("Play Video"). I can't seem to get the video to play across these View Controllers. I add a NSLog in PlayTheVideo and I see that when I push the button, but the video still does not play. I can move the lines of code from PlayTheVideo to viewDidLoad and the video plays immediately so I know the resource file can be found. What I am doing wrong?

```
//ViewController.h
@interface ViewController1 : NSViewController
@property (weak) IBOutlet AVPlayerView *VideoPlayer;
- (void)PlayTheVideo;

@end

//ViewController.m  
@implementation ViewController1
- (void)PlayTheVideo {
    NSURL* videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Clip 1" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    self.VideoPlayer.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    [self.VideoPlayer.player play];
}
@end

//ViewController2.m
@implementation ViewController2
#import "ViewController.h"
- (IBAction)PlayVideo:(id)sender {
    ViewController1 *myClass = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
    [myClass PlayTheVideo];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL* videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Clip1" withExtension:@"mp4"];
self.VideoPlayer.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
[self.VideoPlayer.player play];
```

There a space in a file name..so rename a file name to clip1 at both place in project and in code.

Comment: Log url in console and check the url.